# Assumption of independence in the second Borel–Cantelli lemma can be removed

Tags: probability-theory

I'm stuck proving the next:

Let $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of events. If for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}P\left(A_n|\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=k}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c}\right)=\infty$$ then $$P(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n)=1.$$

Is it enough to assume

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(A_n|\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{i}^{c}\right)=\infty?$$

I was trying to proceed via contradiction but I don't find a way to use it. I was thinking about too to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A\cap A_n)=\infty$ for each event with $P(A)>0$ and to use the hypothesis but such series that I got is not sure to diverge.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mirror the proof of Borel-Cantelli II on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Proof[5]), except when calculating $P(\bigcap_{n=N}^\infty A_n^c)$ you cannot use independence to expand the product; however, you can use conditional probabilities:
$$P\left(\bigcap_{n=N}^\infty A_n^c\right) = P\left(A_N^c\right)P\left(A_{N+1}^c \mid A_N^c\right)P\left( A_{N+2}^c \mid (A_N^c \cap A_{N+1}^c)\right) \cdots$$

Comment: Thanks. That was so clever.